# Issue running 6.3.latest web examples in Wildfly/Tomcat

Tags: optaplanner

I'm having some issues with the 6.3.latest web examples war. When deployed to either EE6 or EE7 via Wildfly or Tomcat, the VRP solution can load the solver config/data and the solver can be started. However once it starts, the solver doesn't solve the problem. So its running, but not solving. Any ideas? I've been stuck on this for a while

Comment: What's the stacktrace in the console? With 6.3, I presume you mean 6.3.0-SNAPSHOT? Which version of WildFly and Tomcat?

Comment: Thanks @GeoffreyDeSmet for the reply. I am running 6.3.0.SNAPSHOT, with WildFly 8.2.0.FINAL. What i've noticed is that whenever i start the VRP solver via /rest/solution, If i then click Terminate Early the chrome console logs 'Solver was already terminated'. After starting my machine this morning, the solver actually worked as expected. However after switching to Tomcat instead of WildFly, i had the same issue again. To problem persists even now that i've reverted back to WildFly. Bit lost..

Comment: I think i've found the issue. I believe it relates to the use of Session to store state. Using a clean browser session seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to using SNAPSHOT's :)